# curl (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl, cannot install composer

Tags: php, http, curl, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install composer via cURL but I cannot find how to download the phar archive.
I've installed cURL from source activating in it's build ssl and ssh compatibility; I need composer to have my php projects interact with Amazon EC2 instances ([Amazon Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/sdk-php2-installing-the-sdk.html)) but, as I try `curl -s "http://getcomposer.org/installer" | php` nothings seems to happen, command "seems" to execute normally but nothing is downloaded neither passed to php.
Evenmore if I try `-sS`option I get the following error `curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl` which also happens if I omit all options.
I tried to follow one similar post on Stack Overflow -> [Post about cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678085/curl-48-an-unknown-option-was-passed-in-to-libcurl) , without having any luck.
Any ideas?
I have  PHP 5.3.10 running on Ubuntu 12.04 with cURL version = `curl 7.29.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of piping the output of cURL into PHP, try downloading the installer first and then running it:

```
$ wget -O installer "http://getcomposer.org/installer"
# php installer
```

Or, if you want to use cURL instead of `wget`, replace the `wget` command with:

```
$ curl -o installer "http://getcomposer.org/installer"
```

Comment: curl -o installer "http://getcomposer.org/installer" outputs the same result as before but using wget did the trick, thanks!