# Git - Git Pull Not Working In Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

Just recently, git in Cygwin has not been behaving correctly. When I try to run a command like `git pull` it does not show anything about the pull. The `git status` command works just fine and shows the appropriate information.

However, all of this works just fine and dandy in Git Bash and Git CMD.

The only thing I've done recently that could have affected Git was install Chef and installed Git for Windows because I couldn't get Git to work in cmd.exe because of an error `cygcrypto 1.0.0 dll is missing`.

Prior to all of this, git worked flawlessly in Cygwin for several months.

Here is a picture of my git command outputs. The top window is Git Bash, and the bottom is Cygwin.

`stract git pull` [output file](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByFgjF8HEbPdZl9DMUdlazUxQ3c&usp=sharing) I had to upload and share it on my Google Drive because the output was too large for any paste hosting site. Pastebin is blocked here at work so I may try to upload it there later.

[image: Picture]

Here is a picture of what's happening after I've removed git from Cygwin and reinstalled it. [image]

Comment: `git pull -v` might reveal something useful (though probably not). After that, you might try `strace git pull`. I'm guessing your git installation got corrupted somehow, so you might try just reinstalling the package as well.

Comment: @jjlin `git pull -v` showed up blank just like `git pull`. I ran `stract git pull` and directed the output to a text file. I added a link to the text file for anyone who would like to read it and hopefully pick up some clue. I'm out at work for the rest of the day so I'll be sure to try any suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: Small update. I tried to reinstall git in Cygwin and uninstalled Git for Windows, but I still have the same result.

Comment: Next update, I completely removed git from Cygwin and reinstalled the git packages. I have a slightly better situation, but not quite. Now I get `error: fetch died of signal 13` when I try to do a `git pull`A picture is attached in the question body.

Comment: Your trace "--- Process 3428 exited with status 0xc0000139" suggest you have a broken cygwin. Follow suggestion on https://cygwin.com/problems.html. and ask help on cygwin mailing list

Comment: I'm just sitting in the same boat. Seems that's due to `cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll` has gone missing (should ship with `openssl` or `libopenssl100`, but it is not there). Git uses Curl to fetch things, so I ran Curl directly, which hung as well - and finally terminated with "error while loading shared libraries: cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". If you meanwhile found a solution, please post an answer (and ping me so I can read it). Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy I never really came up with a surefire solution. I started using Git Bash instead because I could not figure out the problem. One day I did re-run the Cygwin installer and just added one random package. After that `git pull` worked again. I still continue to use Git Bash though because I like that it always shows the branch name without having to use a `git` command

Comment: That issue was [introduced with 1.0.2g1](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-03/msg00020.html) and (temporarily) fixed with g2 in March. Seems like j has broken it again. // Hm, installing a random package? Well, you should make that an answer - did the trick for me as well (selected openssl-devel, thought that wouldn't hurt :) Git works again now. Just `curl <url>` throws an error about ["An unknown option was passed in to libcurl"](https://superuser.com/q/581663/143340)...

Comment: @Izzy with my luck, I figured it was sheer luck lol. I didn't have any feedback from anyone to know if that was actually a fix, but maybe it is. I'll add it as an answer and hope it helps someone in the future. Just to verify you selected the openssl-devel package and installed?

Comment: Yupp, exactly. And the remaining Curl error is most likely due to the fact of Curl-7.52.1 being installed (just a few minutes before) but libcurl-7.47.1 was placed along (7.52.1 wasn't in a few minutes before, now it is so I just updated that now. With the result that my problem is back :( What a mess. // Just seeing there's a lot of other updates pending, so I run those now. Hopefully that fixes it up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to fix the problem is to re-run the Cygwin installer and install a new package. When I fixed my problem I installed some new random package, but in the comments above Izzy installed the `openssl-devel` package.

After re-running the Cygwin setup the problem was fixed.

Note: You can try this method without adding any new packages too. Just let Cygwin go through the setup process again. Doing this does not blow your Cygwin away and start over. It seems to just overwrite the already existing files, and add any new packages you may have added.

Comment: In my case, re-running Cygwin was not even involved – git started working again straight away. It cannot hurt to check for other outdated stuff: In my case, Curl was still broken afterwards due to a version mismatch (Curl was newer than libcurl). Updating libcurl brought back the original issue. Checking and updating the other ~50 pending updates fixed it again :)

Comment: @Izzy sorry I think I misunderstood how you installed your `openssl-devel` package. I added my package by running the installer again. How did you go about installing `openssl-devel`?

Comment: Ah, my fault. I'm using Mobaxterm, which ships with an integrated package manager. For "plain Cygwin", this would correspond to `apt-cyg install` AFAIK (though I used the GUI).

Comment: @Izzy ohhhh ok. Same problem, different terminal, same steps to resolve.  I understand now, thanks!